# Animation jump for parallel\sequential transition in javafx

Tags: java, animation, javafx

I have a program which runs several animations one after the other, and I wanted to add the option to skip to the end of some of the animation, so I used something like this

```
Animation anim = ... ;
anim.setCurrentTime(anim.getTotalDuration());
anim.play();
```

This works most of the times, but there are cases, specially when parallel and sequential transitions are involved that it doesn't work. For example, here is a code to fade in sequentially some circles and rectangles:

```
public void start(Stage stage) {
        Pane root = new Pane();
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 500, 500);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();        

        int N = 10;
        Circle cir[] = new Circle[N];
        Rectangle rect[] = new Rectangle[N];
        for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
            cir[i] = new Circle(10);
            cir[i].relocate(100 + i * 30, 100);
            cir[i].setOpacity(0);
            rect[i] = new Rectangle(20, 20);
            rect[i].relocate(100 + i * 30, 150);
            rect[i].setOpacity(0);

        }
        Button btn = new Button("CLICK");
        root.getChildren().addAll(cir);
        root.getChildren().addAll(rect);
        root.getChildren().addAll(btn);

        btn.setOnAction(evt -> {
            SequentialTransition st1 = new SequentialTransition();
            ObservableList<Animation> kids = st1.getChildren();
            for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
                FadeTransition fade1 = new FadeTransition(Duration.millis(200), cir[i]);
                fade1.setFromValue(0);
                fade1.setToValue(1);
                kids.add(fade1);
            }
            SequentialTransition st2 = new SequentialTransition();
            kids = st2.getChildren();
            for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
                FadeTransition fade2 = new FadeTransition(Duration.millis(200), rect[i]);
                fade2.setFromValue(0);
                fade2.setToValue(1);
                kids.add(fade2);
            }
            Animation anim = new ParallelTransition(st1, st2);
            anim.jumpTo(anim.getTotalDuration());
            anim.play();
        });

    }
```

If you run it as it is right now, nothing will happen. However, if you just jump to the end of st1 or st2 it will work. Also, if instead of jumping to the end of the animation, you jump to one millisecond before

```
anim.jumpTo(anim.getTotalDuration().subtract(Duration.ONE));
```

it does work.
Unfortunately, this is only because both of st1 and st2 end at the same time. If for example you change fade2 to have duration 100 instead of 200, you will only see the circles appearing. This is true whenever you jump to a duration after st2 is finished (1000 millis).

Is there anyway to jump to some part of the animation without these sort of problems? The only workaround that I can think of is to change the rate to some very big number and then just run the animation so it would update on the screen, but even this will only work for when I want to jump all the way to the end of the animation.